# Cardano transaction builder library in Haskell

Tags: plutus, transaction, haskell

Is there a way besides cardano-cli that I can use to construct a transaction using Haskell?

Something like Lucid-cardano npm package, but in Haskell land?

Said library should allow me to construct a tx, its datums, redeemers, adding scripts, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost certainly do this using the `cardano-api` in the same `cardano-node` repository. The code in `cardano-cli` can act as a guide.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. It does seem like it requires a running node?

Comment: Creating the transaction does not require a running `node`, but submitting the transactions to the network will require a `node`.

Comment: `cardano-transactions` seems like what I would have loved to have, but it's not being actively developed anymore:

`let eitherTx = Tx.empty testnetMagic
      & Tx.addInput input0
      & Tx.addOutput output0
      & Tx.addOutput output1
      & Tx.lock
      & Tx.signWith key0
      & Tx.serialize`

Comment: Thanks @Erik, I'll look into it. I was just kinda hopping for a more convenient interface to use (like lucid-cardano in the npm/js world).